# Issue with re-creating a Big Object with the same API Name

Tags: ant, big-object

As part of a POC, someone had created a big object called `StatusTracking__b`. After a few stuff-ups they ended up keeping `StatusTracking3__b` in the system.

The time has come for things to get refactored and I thought I'd go back and use a proper API name for this object, so I tried to deploy a new metadata definition for `StatusTracking__b`. The platform complained with:

> objects/StatusTracking__b.object -- Error: That object name is already
>   in use.

I have gone through all things - metadata API, enterprise WSDL, describes, SOQL queries and I can assure you that this object does not exists - at least form my perspective.

`Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('StatusTracking__b').getDescribe();`

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

To confirm this I created a brand new big object `Boris__b` and also created a bunch of records. Then I deleted this object (and erased it). Second time around I was able to deploy the metadata definition using the same API name `Boris__b` without any issues.

Is this an intermittent bug with big objects or is there something that I could be missing? Where else could the object name be used, without the actual definition (object doesn't exist)?

Comment: The object name isn’t being used by a regular old Custom Object, Platform Event, Custom Metadata etc is it?

Comment: That's the first thing I checked - went through all metadata. No references...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this works as expected. Salesforce support came back with an answer that the prefix of the object name (the API name before the `__`) must be unique across any object types (custom, big, platform events etc.).

To verify this I tried creating a big object and a platform even that had the same prefix as one of my other custom objects, and I got the same error.

Lesson learned the hard way - keep your object names unique across all different types.

Comment: So exactly what I suggested? What had you burned the object name on in the end?

Comment: Well I would've thought you can have the same API name for different types of sObjects... It would've been good to have the same object name with `__c` and `__b` for an example so that you don't have to define mappings etc. rather just replace `c` with `b` in your code :) I'll have to go with a different pattern

Comment: This has bitten me when trying to convert some custom settings to custom metadata. I thought exactly the same as you at the time.